# HeadlessException in my amazon ec2 instance

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having problems to open a pdf from my java app. I am using an amazon ec2 instance linux ami. I am getting this exception:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
```

I am deploying in my tomcar server from the windows cmd, I really don't know if this info matters.

I appreciate the help,

Thanks in advance,

Rodrigo

Comment: Running on windows is probably why you didn't see this error before. By default amazon linux AMI does not include any x server components. They can be installed, but it may be easier to use a different flavor of linux to do that (or you can use a windows instance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, datasage. I'll try to use an instance with ubuntu.